# How to return an Iterator--list<T>:: iterator, as function return value

Tags: c++, iterator, adt, typedef, typename

I was implementing an abstract hash-table container. My `find()` function is properly defined and works fine, as shown below:

```
template <class HashedObj>
HashedObj& HashTable<HashedObj>::find(const HashedObj &x){
    typename list<HashedObj>::iterator itr;
    itr = std::find(theList[hash(x)].begin(), theList[hash(x)].end(), x);
    if(itr == theList[hash(x)].end())
        return ITEM_NOT_FOUND;
    else
        return *itr;
}
```

However, I want to define another function called `findAddress()` that returns `itr` (the iterator) instead of `*itr`. My code is:

```
typedef list<HashedObj>::iterator iterator;
template <class HashedObj>
iterator HashTable<HashedObj>::find(const HashedObj &x){
    return std::find(theList[hash(x)].begin(), theList[hash(x)].end(), x);
}
```

The above will complain that:

```
type std::list<HashedObj, std::allocator<_CharT> > is not derived from type
  HashedTable<HashedObj>.
```

Basically I want to return an iterator type that has been defined by `std` before.

Comment: I don't know about everyone else, but a [Self Contained example](http://sscce.org/#selfcon) may help me figure out what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but both functions have the same name in the code given, while accepting the same parameter. Is this normal? Also, I assume you mean "function called `findAddress()`" instead of "class called `findAddress()`".